# How to get choices to work with Django REST framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    starring = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=(('1','U'),('2','PG'),('3','12A'),('4','12'),('5','15'),('6','18')),default='18')
    length = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}, {self.rating}"
```

and a serialiser:

```
class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ('title','description','starring','rating','length')
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        hours = math.floor(int(data['length']) / 60)
        minutes = int(data['length']) % 60
        data['length'] = f"{hours}h {minutes}m"
        return data
```

and an api view:

```
class FilmList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Film.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FilmSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('rating',)
```

When i use the Django Rest frame work I can filter by the rating, but only if i remove the choices definition from the model. When the choices definition is present on the 'rating' then the filter returns nothing at all.

I would actually like to use that to filter on the 'rating.' Is there a way round this?
thanks

Comment: could you show how you're filtering?

Comment: I am using the Django REST interface, where the screen has the filter button. It is in effect on the url.

Comment: Showing some code for that will be helpful

Comment: There's no code as such isa just a URL, its in the URLS.py as: path('api/film_list/', cinema.apiviews.FilmList.as_view()),